# Is it 'a incident' or 'an incident'?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I came across a [blog](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/dadri-lynching-incident-pm-cant-comment-on-each-and-every-incident-says-bjp-leader/1/490228.html) and the title reads :

> Dadri lynching too minor ***a incident*** for PM to speak: Modi minister

I know that at times, media use 'Headlinese' for writing titles in which they tend to omit articles. But then, here, to my mind, article should be 'an' instead of 'a'.

P.S. Original blog has changed the title now and it reads 'an' instead of 'a'.

Comment: It should be 'an'. I second you!

Comment: I remember this is the second time sites changed their headlines after you putting the question here! Good job! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omitting articles is fine in headlinese; getting them wrong isn't.  You're right that this should be 'an' instead of 'a'.